# What does Angular do with the return value of a parser and a formatter function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am very confused what to return in a parser function and a formatter function on a ngModel controller.

I know that when a value is not valid, you return `undefined` in parser function, otherwise you return the valid value. But wat does Angular do with this value? Is it updating the `$modelValue` or the `$viewValue`, or... ?

I hope someone can explain this to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passes it to the next parser/formatter function and if there is none sets the $modelValue/$viewValue.

NgModelController behaves like this.

`viewValue changes -> parsers -> modelValue -> if changed update model`
`modelValue changes -> formatters -> viewValue -> if changed calls $render`

Generally speaking parsers and formatters have nothing to do with the validation. But if you return `undefined`  in a parser function and the field is `required` the form will be invalid.

Check [this](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#comment-932327906) comment in the old docs for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Is `-> parsers -> modelValue` (and viewValue for formatters) the return value of the function?

Comment: Yes, each parser's return value is used for the value of the next parser. The last parser's return value is used as the modelValue. Same for formatters with one big difference - **the formatters array is traversed backwards**, starting from the last item in the array.